# Entity FrameWork database log

Tags: entity-framework, logging

In DbContext to log the queries Log action is being used. Where is it being invoked under the hood?

```
public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection")
 {
        Database.Log = sql => Debug.Write(sql);
 }
```

Comment: In fact, was trying to search code on codeplex but could not find.

Comment: Entity Framework Core is currently on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework). EF6 is also currently on [Github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6).

Comment: Thanks, I was on same page as codeplex mentioned the github link. I am unable to find particular action property.